# Mirantis Fuel 6.1 : Deployment using scripts

Tags: openstack

I downloaded the virtual box scripts and iso file from Mirantis site.
I started the script launch_8GB.sh to deploy Openstack on 3 nodes.

VM fuel master starts and Fuel setup appears. After I configure everything for network interfaces
(I enable eth2 interface and DHCP because it's connected to NAT Adaper so I have access from host OS and I have access to internet from vm, eth0 is enabled by default and set to be used for network booting other slave nodes), I Save and Quit setup.
After that it's suppose to deploy and install Openstack on fuel master node, but I'm getting this kind of messages.

```
EXT4-fs [7] mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
EXT4-fs [8] mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
```

And it just keeps repeating this messages.
Should I just wait long enough ?

I only changed in configure.sh script sizes of

```
vm_slave_first_disk_mb=35535     #it was 65535
vm_slave_second_disk_mb=35535    #it was 65535
vm_slave_third_disk_mb=35535     #it was 65535
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to wait long enough due to my slow internet connection.